# App only breaks when certain page set as default in Angular 2 (Chrome Only)

Tags: javascript, angular

Edit: This is actually only occurring in Google Chrome.

I have my routes set up like so

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/login',           name: 'Login',       component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'/products',        name: 'Products',    component: ProductComponent,useAsDefault:true},
  {path:'/register',        name: 'Register',    component: RegisterComponent},
  {path:'/checkout',        name: 'Checkout',    component: CheckoutComponent},
  {path:'/movie/:id',       name: 'View',        component: ViewmovieComponent},
  {path:'/profile/',        name: 'Profile',     component: ProfileComponent}
])
```

When setting /products as my default page, the entire app seems to fail silently. However, if I set another page as the home page it works perfectly (including the products page)

I am not seeing any error messages in the console so unsure as to how I can debug the problem. My product component looks like this

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ProductService} from './product.service';
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector    : 'product',
  templateUrl : './templates/product.tpl.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] 
})

export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  public products: Product[];
  constructor(private _productService: ProductService){
    console.log('fired');
  }

  //////////

  letsGo() {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.movies').offset().top - 45
    });
  }

  getProducts(){
    this._productService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(
        data => this.products = data.message,
        error => console.log(error);
      );
  }

  ngOnInit():any{
    this.getProducts();
  }


}
```

Any advice would be great.

Comment: Your `@RouteConfig()` is for the deprecated router. Your imports also are for an old Angular2 version.

Comment: in `public products: Product[];` from where you got the `Product` object?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to redirect from `/` to your product component instead of setting a route default? Maybe that works.

Ex:

```
@RouteConfig([
{path:'', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path:'/login',           name: 'Login',       component: LoginComponent},
{path:'/products',        name: 'Products',    component: ProductComponent},
{path:'/register',        name: 'Register',    component: RegisterComponent},
{path:'/checkout',        name: 'Checkout',    component: CheckoutComponent},
{path:'/movie/:id',       name: 'View',        component: ViewmovieComponent},
{path:'/profile/',        name: 'Profile',     component: ProfileComponent}
```

])

Comment: Tried but same result!

Comment: Are you still using the "old" router? Tried merging to the new one?

Comment: Still using old one (although I didn't realise that until a few comments above this one) if I can't get it to work I will try merging to new. However, considering it works for every other page, there is clearly something happening that can be fixed.

Comment: I can not explain this issue as I am not experienced enough with angular. But it seems that you also are on an old version of angular2. Have you tried copy-pasting your component in another file or given it another component name?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen errors when initializing injected instances get eaten: never get reported.  My guess is there is some problem with your ProductService.  I would look into it, either putting console.log() statements to see where it gets to or by surrounding the body of each function (including the constructor and any code executed from the constructor) in `try { ... } catch(e) { console.error(e); }`.